# VendHQ.api error

Tags: python

Trying to get this code running on RaspberryPi Raspbian:

https://github.com/xoho/vendhq-api-python

I am unsure of the procedure to get the API recognised under that particular system, ergo, I get this error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "cronjob.py", line 27, in <module>
    from VendHQ.api import ApiClient
ImportError: No module named VendHQ.api
```

Any pointers most welcome!

Comment: It doesn't look like this project has a `setup.py` to install the package.  Where did you put it / how did you tell python where it was?

Comment: I actually haven't done so. Is there a way of manually telling Python?